# Efficient implementation of numerical integration in Julia

Tags: performance, julia, integration

I am coding an algorithm in which I have to integrate the product of two functions (costOfNextPeriods and pdf). Because both functions have multiple arguments I wrap them into a single function with one argument. My question is whether this is efficient, knowing that I am most concerned with the performances of my algorithm. Is it good to define functions in-scope like this ?

```
function expCost(y::Float64, period::Int, instance::Instance, pwla::Pwla)
    dist = instance.distributions[period]
    functionToIntegrate(demand) = costOfNextPeriods(y, demand, period+1, instance, pwla)*pdf(dist,demand)
    return quadgk(functionToIntegrate,0,Inf)[1]
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Instance` and `Pwla` types and `costOfNextPeriods` function are properly defined (i.e. the Julia compiler can inter concrete types on them) the pattern you are using should be efficient. You can run `@code_warntype` on your function to make sure it is the case (if you get `Any` or *red* ink output somewhere you have a problem). If you posted a fully reproducible example I could show you how to check it.

However, note that if you use `expCost` function somewhere in a hot portion of the code if will not be efficient. The reason is that `quadgk` function is not type stable itself (I assume you use `quadgk` function from the QuadGK.jl package). Because of this the Julia compiler is not able to infer the return type of `expCost`. In such cases it is best to explicitly declare function return type like this:

```
function expCost(some_arguments...)::Float64
    # whatever you do internally
end
```

(here I annotated the return value as `Float64` but please change it to whatever is your expected return value type)

Also when you run `@code_warntype` on your `expCost` function I am sure you will see this return value type instability indicated as `Any` in *red* ink.